# can not get property laravel Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

i am New in laravel and when i try to run this query it gives no result 
    while all result are in database
Here is the snapshot of  error
[image]

**Code**

```
$age=24
    $campaign = Campaigns::select( 'id','startdate', 'enddate' )->where( [
                [ 'minage', '<', $age ],
                [ 'maxage', '>', $age ]

            ] )->orWhere( function ( $query ) use ( $age ) {
                $query->where( [
                    [ 'minage', '<', $age ],
                    [ 'maxage', '>', $age ],
                ] );
            } )->orderBy( 'first', 'DESC' )->get();
```

Please Don't do negitive rating If you want please suggested updation in My Question

Comment: Seems like you'll need to post more code to complete this question - where is $age being defined? Are you looping through $campaign? If so, where?

Comment: code is update And No i am Not looping through $campaign
$campagin contains the   Query result
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what property the `Evaluated Expression` is trying to access. When you're creating `$campaigns`, you're only requesting `id`, `startdate`, and `enddate`. So unless `proxies` is a relationship, it doesn't exist. If `proxies` is a relationship that you're trying to access, then you need to select all the fields on the campaigns table needed for the relationship. If you're saying that `$campaigns` is empty, then you need to evaluate your query. It's trying to get any campaign where `minage` is less than age AND `maxage` is greater than age OR (minage < age AND maxage > age).

Comment: @aynber i am Just try to run following query i mentioned in my Q 
and proxies is not relationship  
Query is right it working perfectly fine when i run in SQL format

Comment: Can you show the query you're running in straight SQL?

Comment: @aynber sure 2min please

Comment: SELECT id,startdate ,enddate FROM campaigns  where minage <24 and maxage >24

Comment: I'd suggest removing your `orWhere`, since it's just a duplication of your first `where`. Then do `dd($campaigns);` to see if it contains anything, instead of using the Evaluate Expression function. Another way to test your code without running the whole page would be to use `php artisan tinker`, which allows you to run php/laravel functions on the command line.